# Telegram бот. Поместить текст в поле ввода сообщений пользователя

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

Нужно по кнопке отправить пользователю сообщение и вставить текст-шаблон в его поле, чтобы он его подкорректировал и отправил обратно.
InlineKeyboardButton.WithSwitchInlineQueryCurrentChat проблему не решает, т.к. вставляет имя бота в текстовую строку.
Может кто-то сталкивался. Гугл говорит, что этого сделать нельзя.

Comment: И правильно гугл говорит. Боты не всемогущи.

Comment: Вы можете юзеру выдать менюшку, где он на что-то готовое нажмет.

Comment: Да, спасибо, я в курсе про менюшку. Дело в том, что она сразу выполняет команду без аргументов. А мне нужен инструмент, позволяющий вставлять команду пользователю в текстовое поле, чтобы он только аргументы дописывал